# Where does the method ValidateRelyingParty derive from in itfoxtec-identity-saml2?

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

When implementing the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 library I was unsure how to find the method definition for ValidateRelyingParty() at https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestIdPCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L35

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample shows how a SAML 2.0 identity provider (IdP) insures that the calling relying party is trustworthy. The ValidateRelyingParty method is implemented in https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestIdPCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L134

The ValidateRelyingParty method instantiate a list of trusted relying parties and return the calling relying party or fails.

An identity provider (IdP) should validate if a relying party is allowed to login/logout and most important only respond to a trusted relying party url.